# ANDROID: How to fix the position of a ImageButton relative to the background?

Tags: android, layout, background, imagebutton, android-relativelayout

How to fix the position/layout of a ImageButton/Button/ImageView relative to the background?

I'd tried something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_img"
>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="52dip"
    android:layout_height="52dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="87dip"        
    android:background="@drawable/btn1"
/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I change the display resolution, the background_img stretch to cover the new area, but the ImageButton doesn't streetch and doesn't respect the bottom margin proportionately.

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You give the ImageButton an explicit width and height, so it will never stretch. You want it to stretch based on how big it's parent is?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you hardcoded the height and with.  Set them to fill_parent and it will then fit the margin.

Comment: fill_parent will fit the margin, but how to fix a size/position relative to background? Ex.: x % background_width (not 52dip), y % background_height (not 52dip) and z % background_bottom (not 87dip)?

Comment: If I understand right, I think the best option would be to use a `LinearLayout` instead and set the height or width to 0dip and then the weight to the percentage you want.